# @font-face misbehaving in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, font-face

I need to use a custom font, and I have followed every trick in the book, including the plethora of solutions that seem to have worked for others here on Stack.

My `_text.css.scss` file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DroidSerif';
  src:font-url('DroidSerif.eot');
  src:font-url('DroidSerif.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  font-url('DroidSerif.svg#droidserif') format('svg'),
  font-url('DroidSerif.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 { font-family: 'DroidSerif', 'serif' }
```

I go to the web page and it still shows a sans-serif font.

I have the fonts in the `app/assets/fonts/` directory and I added:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts"
```

to my `application.rb` file.

Any ideas?  This is a Rails 3.2 app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to resolve itself after a restart of my machine.

EDIT: The h-tags do have commas between them in the actual code.